# Visibility turns to none after postback automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

I tried to make the visibility of a div through javascript.

```
  <asp:LinkButton class="ProfilePageDetailLinks" ID="lbtnPersonal" runat="server" OnClientClick="VisibleTab('PersonalDetails')">Show Details</asp:LinkButton>
    <div id="PersonalDetails">
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>

function VisibleTab(str) {
    if (document.getElementById(str).style.display == 'none') {
        document.getElementById(str).style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById(str).style.display = 'none';
    }
```

But after the postback, the div is hiding automatically.

Please check the code below... Its not working as expected.. How to make it works.. Thats my actual doubt...

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div runat="server" id='G2'>
            content</div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClientClick="javascript:document.getElementById('G2').style.visibility = 'visible';"
            runat="server" Text="show" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" OnClientClick="javascript:document.getElementById('G2').style.visibility = 'hidden';"
            runat="server" Text="hide" />
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: do u know after post back page refreshes again. it is showing you the div was after first page load. so if you want to do such type of thing then you have make div runat="server" then apply code to it

Comment: please add more details so this question can actually be answered

Comment: I put runat=server for the div and add the codes. But still not working....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `return false;` to `avoid` your `postback`

```
OnClientClick="VisibleTab('PersonalDetails'); return false;"
```